# QGIS batch clip does not work. One by one it works fine

Tags: qgis, clip, batch

When using a batch clip QGIS gets stuck at some point giving me an unknown error, while just clipping one by one works just fine. Any idea what could be causing this?

EDIT:

log says:

```
Uncaught error while executing algorithm
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "E:/usbgis/apps/qgis2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 203, in execute
            self.processAlgorithm(progress)
          File "E:/usbgis/apps/qgis2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\Clip.py", line 113, in processAlgorithm
            if not engine.intersects(in_feat.constGeometry().geometry()):
        Exception: unknown
```

Comment: Did you clip all the files manually? If not, maybe one of those you didn't clip have a faulty geometry.

Comment: With one by one I meant manually, which works fine, so geometry should not be the problem (was the first thing I checked).

Comment: Yeah, but did you clip all your files, or only a part of them?

Comment: Oh, only a part of them. To check if manually clipping worked better when the batch proved to have some issues

Comment: Could you run a check for geometry faults for the up to now unclipped layers? maybe something turns up.

Comment: Did that, but nothing showed up. Maybe something to do with the filesize/number of features that makes it hard to use in a batch? Problem with that is that I thought that a batch is just the same as multiple single manual processes, but automated.

Comment: It actually is. Possible error could be a too long path to your files. Had this problem sometimes, but sadly I don't remember whether QGis then explicitly tells you so.

Comment: Okay, next idea: Half your batches, again and again. All files don't work, maybe there's a threshold below which it works?

Comment: It finishes one clip and then I get the error, sometimes I even get it at the first clip. Whatever, I'll just do them one by one manually. Gonna take me a day, but has to be done. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: You could build a graphical model for 10 to 20 clippings in a row, at least lessening your workload a bit.

Comment: What do you mean with a graphical model?

Comment: QGis lets you build models, which can combine several steps to a process where you simply have to define your input and where to save the output. Try 'ctrl+alt+m'.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of QGIS? Try with the more stable 2.18, which is a long-term release version. If that solves your issue, definitely make a bug report. https://issues.qgis.org/

Comment: I am using 2.18.11. Thing is, I am using USBGIS because I am not allowed to install software on this pc (strict privacy policies and they are scared). The error might only appear because of the use of USBGIS.